# Image processing: Make pixels value in an image to either 0 or 255

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing

[Satellite mask image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvsrE.jpg)

For image segmentation, I want to label pixel value 0 and 255 only. But my mask dataset contains other pixels value as well. So how can I perform image processing to threshold the value to only 0 and 255.
I only need python code for that.

I tried thresholding but the result was even worse. So expecting better solution for it.

Comment: Using lossy JPEG images as a mask is a bad idea. You should use lossless PNG or TIFF.

Comment: "the result was even worse": please explain.